# Is 2 hours 20 minutes enough for a layover in Frankfurt Airport?

Tags: short-connections, lufthansa, fra

I'm studying abroad in Florence this summer and I'm trying to decide on the best layover option (flying from NYC). I've narrowed it down to Frankfurt via Lufthansa, but I'm paranoid about delays...would a 2 hour 20 minute layover be enough time? Or should I opt for 5 hours instead?

Comment: Tip: the outside corridors of the Biblioteca delle Oblate are a popular place to study, the shade protects from the heat and you can even see the Duomo. Another tip: there are many, many excellent restaurants but I'd like to recommend Del Fagioli as the food is simply heavenly, the atmosphere is authentic (to the level of not bothering with an English menu). I am now returning to Firenze yearly just to visit my favorite restaurants :D

Comment: 2:20 is probably fine if everything goes smoothly. If everything *doesn't* go smoothly, your layover can turn into a race across the airport to catch your connection in a hurry. I once had a 2:30 layover disappear completely between a late departure and a problem with the jetway that delayed unboarding for 45 minutes.

Answer (score 15):

Typically, an hour is already enough in Frankfurt.

However, there can always be an uncommonly long line or some other issue, and then two hours are better.
Your main concern should be that LH typically doesn't wait for connections, and those are often delayed. As a result, your next leg might leave before you ever get there. On the other hand, there are multiple flights to Florence, so it depends a bit on how bad it is for you to arrive some hours later.

I would recommend the two hours choice; you should be fine for 99%.

Comment: I'd like to disagree with the statement that an hour is already enough -- Coming from NY, the OP will have a pass through security and immigration. But 2 hours are of course very different...

Comment: I go through FRA multiple times a year (coming from the USA), and normally I'm at the next gate ready to board within 30 - 45 mins. But I walk _fast_, which also gets me to the front of most lines - your mileage may vary.

Comment: I regularly went through Frankfurt airport last year.  My company typically booked my schedule with about an hour layover.  I'm really tall and walk fast and was able to make it.  It helps if you pack light and know the drill for the security screening.  (Empty pockets, Laptop/Tablet in its own x-ray container).  Everyone that I spoke to that works in Frankfurt airport speaks English, so don't be afraid to ask for help if you get turned around.

Answer (score 7):

Should be plenty. Make sure that you have this booked on a SINGLE BOOKING and a single ticket. If it's a single booking and you can't make the connection, the airline will simply put you on the next available flight. Lufthansa has six non-stops from FRA to FLR per day with the last one leaving around 9.30pm.

If it is two different tickets and you miss your connection, you are on your own.

Comment: He should also make sure that he gets all boarding passes when he checks for the first flight.

Comment: I think the assumption that the OP is male is questionable. Our unconscious biases are showing....